# How to post the model with foreign key?

Tags: python, django

I have a model like this

one has a foreign key of the other.

```
class MyCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='description')

class MyItem(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploaded/')
    category = models.ForeignKey(MyCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    @property
    def category_name(self):
        return self.category.name

class MyItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyItemSerializer

class MyCategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyCategory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyCategorySerializer
```

Now I want to upload the file to `MyItem` and set the category at the same time.

At first, I try this. ( I have one category of data which has id = 1)

```
curl -X POST -F file=@mypng.jpg -F 'category=1' http://localhost/items/
```

it shows `Exception Value: (1048, my_category_id cannot be null)`

category=1 dosen't accepted as foreign key.

So, is it possible to use the `curl` command to set the `ForeignKey`?

**Solution**

I added the `category_id` in fields of serializer

```
class MyItemSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    file = serializers.FileField()
    category_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    category_id = serializers.IntegerField() # add here.
    class Meta:
        model = Donation
        fields = [
            'file',
            'category_id', # add here
            'created_at',
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `category=1` so Django expects to send a `category` object but if you need to send the id of the object, set `category_id=1`

```py
curl -X POST -F file=@mypng.jpg -F 'category_id=1' http://localhost/items/
```

Comment: Thank you @Mohamed Hamza, I use 'category_id=1' but still same error occurs. mysteriously I have confirmed there is `category_id` as bigint in table by `phpMyAdmin`

Comment: Could you show me where exactly you create the object? we need to make it like that: 

`item = MyItem.objects.create(file=file, category_id=category_id)`

Comment: I see,,, I don't have any custom `create` . I just use django-framework-default default. I added the view class source to the article.

Comment: I solved with changing `serializer`. At first I thought serializer is not related with upload. but it was wrong. I updated the article. Your comment gives me the big hint to solve. thank you very much.